# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.inrev.crm.bean.IRSurveyQuestions

Tags: java, list, arraylist, javabeans

if any one help me why i am geting following this exception here

```
List<abc> listQues=null;
for(int i=0;i<surveyIds.size();)
        {


            List<abc> listQue = (ArrayList<abc>) getHibernateTemplate().find("from abc as q where q.surveyId=" + surveyIds.get(0) + " order by q.pageNo asc, q.sortOrder asc");
            listQues.add((abc) listQue);


            i++;
        }
```

i am geting following Exception Here

**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.inrev.crm.bean.IRSurveyQuestions**

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Pretty simple it seems that you are getting `com.inrev.crm.bean.IRSurveyQuestions` type of objects but trying to cast the same to `ArrayList<abc>` which is an error.

Comment: Does not look like that. Bean class is `IRSurveyQuestions`. It should have been a `list` of `abc` type.

Comment: i have changed bean name

Comment: What is the return type of `getHibernateTemplate().find()`?

Comment: what change you have done. I don't see.

Comment: You are trying to cast `List<abc>` to `abc` and that is the reason of this exception. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
listQues.add((abc) listQue); --???
```

How can you cast `List<abc>` to `abc`?? Change

```
List<abc> listQues=null;
```

to

```
List<List<abc>> listQues=null;
```

and then on the line where you are adding questions list

```
listQues.add(listQue);
```